# canvas doesnt draw in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Why arent rectangles being drawn in loop? 
I just started making snake game n tried to draw body of snake via loop,but for some reason ctx doesnt draw in  loop.
if i write rect without loop it works.

```
var canv = document.getElementById('canv');
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

var snake = [];
snake[0] = {x:100, 100};
snake[1] = {x:90, 100};
snake[2] = {x:80, 100};

var i;

function draw() {
   for (i = 0; i > snake.length; i++) {
     ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
     ctx.rect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, 22, 300); 
     ctx.fill();
 }

setInterval(draw,100);
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code; then you can check your draw implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is wrong(you had an infinite loop and make it less than `i < snake.length`):

```
function draw() {
    for (i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.rect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, 22, 300); 
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```